# CRM RibbonWorkbech - 3rd Party Librarys

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, ribbonx, xrmservicetoolkit

I have a JS function that is running on a custom button that is visible on a View not a form.

The function requires XrmServiceToolkit to complete it's purpose, therefore on the ribbon workbench on my custom button I added a action to call the XrmServiceToolkit library, but there needs to be a function name.

Does anyone know the correct way to get this working

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite "dummy" function for this purpose is `isNaN`

```
<JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="isNaN" Library="$webresource:myjslib" />
```

Comment: hi @Alex - I found an example where this had been used, however this threw a different error stating that `XrmServiceToolkit.REST.retrieveRecord requires the errorCallback parameter is a function.`

Comment: The error is unrelated, you have a bug where you invoke `retrieveRecord`. The fact that the error pops up means the library is being loaded correctly.